# Trouble updating Meteor users object when creating subscription plan with Stripe API

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Everything thus far works great. User logs into website, goes to the premium page and can choose a package to order via Stripe Checkout. Once the customer completes the order, the customer is created on the Stripe Dashboard and is signed up for the subscription. Great.

However, I have a problem updating the Meteor.users object with the subscription information. This is how the code looks:

```
 initiateCustomer: function(email, token){
  var email = email;
  var token = token;

  var newCustomer = new Future();

  Meteor.call('createCustomer', token, email, function(error, stripeCustomer){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      var customerId = stripeCustomer.id;
      var plan = "Premium";

      Meteor.call('createSubscription', customerId, plan, function(error, response){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          try {

            var currentUser = Meteor.userId();

            var user = {
            _id: currentUser
          }

            var subscription = {
              customerId: customerId,
              subscription: {
                plan: {
                  name: plan,
                  used: 0
                },
                payment: {
                  card: {
                    type: stripeCustomer.sources.data[0].brand,
                    lastFour: stripeCustomer.sources.data[0].last4
                  },
                  nextPaymentDue: response.current_period_end
                }
              }
            };

            Meteor.users.update(user, {
              $set: subscription
            }, function(error, response){
              if (error){
                console.log(error);
              } else {
                newCustomer.return(user);
              }
            });
          } catch(exception) {
            newCustomer.return(exception);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return newCustomer.wait();
},
```

It's the `Meteor.users.update()` operator that is giving me problems because it's not updating the User object like it's supposed to. After the update is complete, the user object is supposed to have the _id, email and subscription information inside the users object. However, the subscription key is never added to the user object once the Method call is complete.

Comment: Is it updating only some of the fields, or none of them?

Comment: Nothing updates. I just found out that in the Meteor.users.update function's callback, the response is "1" and the `newCustomer.return(user)` block returns undefined.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd want a users object to look post update?

Comment: The object post update is supposed to have these keys: `{_id, email, customerId, subscription};`

Comment: You're not getting into your catch block, correct?

Comment: Correct. I'm not getting anything in my catch block at all.

Comment: Do you have `allow` and `deny` rules for `Meteor.users` and do you have a schema for it?

Comment: Also where is this code located? Is this in a shared method? When it acknowledges the write with "1" is that on the server?

Comment: I have not set allow and deny rules for `Meteor.users`. Is that a requirement? I was under the impression that it wasn't necessary in the newest versions of Meteor. Also, the code is a Method and is located on the server. It's not a shared method and only is invoked when a user submits credit card information via Stripe Checkout. The "1" result is on server.

Comment: Do you use `collection2`, or any other package for object validation?

Comment: @HubertOG Nope. I don't use any such package.

Comment: I just console logged `Meteor.user()` server side and the subscription is actually added to the user object. But why is it not appearing when I look at it via client?

Comment: Ok, I found and fixed the problem. I had to specifically create another pub/sub pair just to publish the extra fields I inserted. Wow, all this for just this little error.